# jquery help trying to reduce $(this) statements within on method

Tags: jquery

Would there be a more elegant way to write the following jQuery code?  for some reason I just don't think all the find('.section') statements are necessary...but if that is fine, please let me know.

```
function jqPanels() {
$('#jqpanel .jqpanel-container').each(function() {
$(this).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        if ($(this).find('.section').next().css('display') == "block") {
          $(this).find('.section').removeClass('jqarrow-down');
        } else {
          $(this).find('.section').addClass('jqarrow-down');
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($(this).find('.section').next().css('display') == "block") {
          $(this).find('.section').addClass('jqarrow-up');
        } else {
          $(this).find('.section').removeClass('jqarrow-down jqarrow-up');
        }
    },
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var mclass=$(this).find('.section').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        var $mcontent = $("#" + mclass);
        if ($mcontent.is(':hidden')) {
          $mcontent.delay(100).fadeIn().slideDown().prev().addClass('jqarrow-up').removeClass('jqarrow-down');
        } else {
          $mcontent.delay(100).slideUp().prev().addClass('jqarrow-down');
        }
     }              
    });//end on event handler       
});//end each loop
//*/
}
```

update:

Here is my modified code which appears to be working

```
function jqPanels() {
$('#jqpanel .jqpanel-container').each(function() {
    var $section = $(this).find('.section');
$(this).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        if ($section.next().css('display') == "block") {
          $section.removeClass('jqarrow-down');
        } else {
          $section.addClass('jqarrow-down');
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($section.next().css('display') == "block") {
           $section.addClass('jqarrow-up');
        } else {
           $section.removeClass('jqarrow-down jqarrow-up');
        }
    },
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var mclass=$(this).find('.section').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        var $mcontent = $("#" + mclass);
        if ($mcontent.is(':hidden')) {
          $mcontent.delay(100).fadeIn().slideDown();
          $section.addClass('jqarrow-up').removeClass('jqarrow-down');
        } else {
          $mcontent.delay(100).slideUp();
          $section.addClass('jqarrow-down');
        }
     }              
    });//end on event handler       
});//end each loop
//*/
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: well, for one, you don't need the .each statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache the `.section` by doing this:

```
var $section = $(this).find('.section');
```

And change your statements to use that variable, like this for example:

```
$section.removeClass('jqarrow-down');
```

I also don't see any reason to do the binding in a loop... just do

```
$('#jqpanel .jqpanel-container').on({...});
```

Comment: would i have to recreate var $section, within each event? or can i reference that one time from one var $section?

Comment: Nope, you could set the var inside the each function.

Comment: then that is "good" reason to have an each method for this specific code!  Thank you Jason P!

Comment: True, though I'm not sure if that would gain you much.

Comment: I was just trying to reference this, and make the code look cleaner, rather than having $(this) all over the place.

Comment: I think you should as much as possible... but I'm not sure binding elements in a loop is a good trade-off. I'm not sure on the performance implications, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I totally understand and will keep my eyes open for that.  Appreciate the creativity.

Comment: Would it also be better to do `$('#jqpanel').on({...}, '.jqpanel-container');`?

Comment: And use the same callback for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I think it depends on how many `.jqpanel-container` there are (the more elements there are, the better it is to do delegation), and whether they are dynamic (in which case you'd have to do delegation).

Comment: Yes I will have multiple .jqpanel-container's within one #jqpanel, and would like to reduce the amount of $(this) statements used.  the each method gives me a way to do that as jason pointed out.